# How can I make two column from same table by two query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I've two query from same table but by two condition but how can I make two column for this two conditional count.

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM TBL_FT WHERE STATUS = 'X';
SELECT Count(*) FROM TBL_FT WHERE STATUS = 'Y' and
LOGDATE>trunc(sysdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'X' THEN 1 END),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Y' AND LOGDATE > trunc(sysdate) THEN 1 END)
FROM TBL_FT
```

You can also add a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE STATUS IN ('X', 'Y');
```

Comment: taking long time to execute

Comment: Try adding the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this -

```
SELECT SUM(CASE
               WHEN STATUS = 'X' THEN
                1
               ELSE
                0
             END) FIRST_VAL,
       SUM(CASE
                      WHEN STATUS = 'Y'
                           AND LOGDATE > TRUNC(SYSDATE) THEN
                       1
                      ELSE
                       0
                    END) second_val
         FROM TBL_FT;
```

Comment: oops my bad.. corrected .. thanks @a_horse_with_no_name